# Convert from switch case statement to a value in Swift

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement, case

Maybe this is a stupid question

I have a switch case statement like this:

```
        self.text = type.rawValue
        switch type {
        case .teuro:
            self.backgroundColor =  UIColor.sapphireColor()
        case .lesson:
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        case .profession:
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.pinkyPurpleColor()
        }
```

Is there any way to write it in something like this example:

```
        self.backgroundColor = {
            switch type {
            case .teuro:
                return  UIColor.sapphireColor()
            case .lesson:
                return  UIColor.orangeColor()
            case .profession:
                return UIColor.pinkyPurpleColor()
            }
        }
```

Any comment or answer is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are nearly there!

You've created a closure that returns a color, and are assigning it to a `UIColor` property, but a closure is not a color!

You just need to call (invoke) the closure to *run* it, so that it returns the color you want:

```
self.backgroundColor = {
    switch type {
    case .teuro:
        return  UIColor.sapphireColor()
    case .lesson:
        return  UIColor.orangeColor()
    case .profession:
        return UIColor.pinkyPurpleColor()
    }
}() // <---- notice the brackets!
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually you don't wanna mix your models and your UI, and only need to use this colors inside one view

That's why I ended up creating such extensions, which are only accessible inside current file of the view:

```
private extension Type {
    var backgroundColor: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .teuro:
            return .sapphireColor()
        case .lesson:
            return .orangeColor()
        case .profession:
            return .pinkyPurpleColor()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, I think about create color var like previous answer. But your answer is better.

Comment: @HoSiTuan sure, my approach suits best for `SwiftUI` when you don't wanna switches inside your view hierarchy for better readability. And for `UIKit` it's not that necessarily and block can be used too, especially if your view code is small

Answer (score 2):

Sweeper is absolutely correct, that you can initialize this with a closure by adding the missing `()` at the end. So that is the literal answer to your question.

But Philip also is correct, that it would be best to add an extension to your enumeration type to define a mapping between colors and your cases. It abstracts the color scheme from both the calling point (e.g. ensuring that you have a consistent application of colors throughout the app, while never repeating yourself), but at the same time, avoids entangling the UI color scheme with some basic enumeration type.

But I would like to take it a step further, namely to extend this observation to the `text` property, too. You should not use the `rawValue` strings in your UI. The raw codes (if you have them at all) should not be conflated with the strings you want to display in the UI. One is a coding question, while the other is a UI question.

So, I would not only move `color` into an extension, but also the display text, e.g. I would define a `text` property:

```swift
extension MyEnumerationType {
    var text: String { rawValue }
}
```

Then you could do:

```swift
self.text = myEnumerationInstance.text
```

Now here I am still using `rawValue`, but I am abstracting it away from the UI. The reason is that you might want to eventually support different strings, but not change your `rawValue` codes. E.g., you might want to support localization at some point:

```swift
extension MyEnumerationType {
    var text: String { NSLocalizedString(rawValue, comment: "MyEnumerationType") }
}
```

Or you might have a `switch` statement inside this `text` computed property. But it avoids the tight coupling of your enumeration’s internal representation (the `rawValue`) from the UI.

So, bottom line, not only should you abstract the color scheme out of the type itself, but you should abstract display text, too. That way, you can change your display text at some future date, but not break code that relied on the old `rawValue` values.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to create one color var inside the enum.

Here is the example

```
enum Type {
    case type1, type2
    
    var color: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .type1:
            return .black
            
        case .type2:
            return .yellow
        }
    }
}
```

Use

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let type: Type = .type1
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = type.color
    }
}
```